# change the name of control idOK of SaveFileDialog

Tags: c#

change the name of control idOK of SaveFileDialog from button "save" to "ok"

Comment: Do you hate your users that much?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this CodeProject article has what you need:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dialog/CustomizeFileDialog.aspx

(Hooray for google)

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to listen for some messages (like `WM_ACTIVATE` etc) from the dialog to get the window handle that you can use to customize it. Here's a Codeproject article that describes this in more detail and has sample code: [Customizing OpenFileDialog in .NET](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dialog/OpenFileDialogEx.aspx)

By the way, just so you're aware, this might be more complex than what you were anticipating for just changing a text slightly.